# RuntimeException Extension in Java

Tags: java, exception

I have simply added an extension to the EmptyStackException in Java to show an error message. I have put this file under the same package, but I get the error:

```
"The constructor EmptyStackException(String) is undefined"
```

EmptyStackException.java:

```
package mypackage;

public class EmptyStackException extends RuntimeException{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  public EmptyStackException(String message){
      super(message);
   }
}
```

Should be something very simple. But I got stuck!
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the whole code showing you creating `object` of your class?

Comment: Could you post the code that's actually giving you the problem? i.e., where you're calling this constructor

Answer (score 3):

You have defined your own `EmptyStackException`, but Java supplies `java.util.EmptyStackException`, and [its only constructor takes no arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EmptyStackException.html#EmptyStackException%28%29), which means your code that you think uses your own `EmptyStackException` actually is using `java.util.EmptyStackException`.

To extend `EmptyStackException`, define your own:

```
public MyEmptyStackExceptionWithMessage extends EmptyStackException {
```

In the constructor, call `super()` and store your own message.

Comment: Or alternatively use the fully qualified name of class, including package name. ie `mypackage.EmptyStackException`

Comment: @Dgrin91 True, that's possible, but the OP is attempting an "extension".  I think the OP is attempting to extend `EmptyStackException`, not define another one.

Comment: @rgettman: thanks, but that doesn't work either! I get the same error msg for the super(msg)

Comment: Don't call `super(message)`; there is no constructor in `EmptyStackException` that takes a `String`.  If you're going to call "super", use `super();` with no arguments, and store the `message` string as an instance variable in your own class.  (If you don't call `super();`, then Java will add an implicit call to `super()` as the first statement in your constructor.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to replace the existing `EmptyStackException` class with one of your own; this is always a very bad idea (and in many Java environments, not possible.) Probably the compile error is arising because although you're trying to construct an instance of your class, the Java compiler is actually trying to instantiate `java.util.EmptyStackException` which indeed has no one-argument constructor. Basically, if you need to define your own exception types, choose names that aren't already used by a platform class -- you'll avoid a lot of hassle. And if your goal is truly to replace the Java API class: give up. It's not going to happen.